# How to Complete a task via API in Twilio?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-taskrouter

```
const completeTask = async(taskid) => {
  console.log(taskid)
  completeTask = twilioWorkspaceClient.tasks(taskid).update({
    assignmentStatus: 'completed',
    reason: 'completed',
    attributes: JSON.stringify({
      type: 'other'
    })
  })
  console.log('task completed');
}
```

I tried this code to make my task completed but I think its not the right way and it is also not working.
If anyone have any idea please help me out.
regards,

Comment: what is your error? is it not printing out "task completed"?

Comment: yes Its not printing "task completed"  and also not updating task status on Twilio portal

Comment: is taskid printing? can you include your complete code?